# Nuxtjs. loggedIn is still false after setUser

Tags: authentication, nuxt.js

I have two websites. On the first the user logs in (creating a local storage value), on the second (the one I am trying to program) the storage value is rechecked for login but is returning false. What do I need to modify?

NB: I know this is a strange situation, but there is a reason for it so it cannot be changed.

In strategies I have...

```js
local: {
  token: { required: false, maxAge: 90000 },   
  user: { autoFetch: false, property: false },     
  endpoints: {
    user: false,
    login: false,
    logout: false,
  },
},
```

... property being set to false as the storage value is a more complex version of {"firstName":"abc","lastName":"def"}, i.e. not in a user field.

In the main vue file I have...

```js
created() {
  var savedData = localStorage.getItem("ngStorage-user");
  if (savedData !== null) {
    alert(savedData); // Displays the string that I expect.
    this.$auth.setUser(JSON.parse(savedData)); // The setUser call.
    alert(this.$auth.user.firstName); // Displays 'abc'.
    alert(this.$auth.loggedIn); // Displays false
  }
}
```

PS: I have reviewed the similar queries, but none seems to match this.

====

Addendum: I have possibly solved this, and improved it at the same time by checking that the token is valid.

Added a call to tokencheck in the API which checks the token and returns minimal user details.

```
      local: {
        token: { required: false, maxAge: 90000, property: "token" },   
        user: { autoFetch: false, property: false },     
        endpoints: {
          user: { url: `${process.env.API_URL}tokencheck` },
          login: false,
          logout: false,
        },
      },
```

And then in Vue

```
  created() {
    var savedData = localStorage.getItem("ngStorage-user");
    if (savedData !== null) {
      var parsedSaveData = JSON.parse(savedData);
      this.$auth.setUserToken(parsedSaveData.token) // Which calls the 'user' endpoint
      .then(res => { this.$auth.setUser(res.data); })
      .catch(() => { this.error = true; });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Try to `await this.$auth.setUser` and also, I recommend checking the Vue devtools rather than using `alert/console.log`.

Comment: My modified code code seems to work. I have a different problem where user logs in to 2nd website directly where your 'await' idea may be useful so have not yet closed this thread.